# Using arabic language in playfab to create leaderboard

Tags: unity-game-engine, arabic, leaderboard, playfab

I’m trying to make arabic leaderboard using playfab , does it support Arabic language? I mean can i write the names and number in arabic ? I searched alot about this problem but there is no clear answer

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about Arabic, but the name of the leaderboard is the name of the statistic and it is of type string. Displayed in the ranking is the player's display name, which supports a string type of 3 to 25 characters. The value in the leaderboard is the value in the statistics, which supports int32 type.